# HtmlAgilityPack разных версий работает по-разному C#

Tags: c#, winforms, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Есть программа, в которой при помощи xpath-запроса можно получить ссылки на изображения.
Запрос:

```
var screen = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//textarea[@class='hidearea']/a");
```

Данные в Html Agility Pack загружаются следующим образом:

```
HD.LoadHtml(responseToString);
```

Где `responseToString` содержит следующий код:
https://jsfiddle.net/7fhyv1an/

Но переменная screen всегда возвращает null. При этом, аналогичный код в другой программе работает как надо. Единственное отличие: в программе, где он работает, версия Html Agility Pack - **1.4.5.9**. А в программе, где он не работает, стоит Html Agility Pack версии **1.11.22**.

Еще недавно заметил такую особенность на версии **1.4.5.9**:
программа отработала первую ссылку, скачала картинки.
Я вставляю эту же ссылку второй раз (либо новую, без разницы), но картинки уже не находит. Выдает ошибку, что ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

При этом, данной программой я пользуюсь уже года 2. И всегда все было нормально. А теперь вот такая проблемка...

Comment: А что возвращает `SelectNodes`? На всякий случай, если не удастся побороть xpath, есть NuGet пакет, расширение для `HtmlAgilityPack` - `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`. Оно позволяет делать `QuerySelector` запросы как в JavaScript.

Comment: @aepot `SelectNodes` в первый раз возвращает коллекцию ссылок на картинки, а во второй раз возвращает `null`. Но при этом, после перезапуска приложения код работает адекватно. Но снова 1 раз получишь значения и он снова возвращает null. Я `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` объявлял глобально изначально, затем создал локальную версию в методе чисто под картинки. Думал, что раз я в коде несколько раз перезагружаю данные методом `LoadHtml`, то это может сказываться, но тоже никакого эффекта не дало. Спасибо. Никогда не делал запросы через JS, придется разбираться чуть что.

Comment: А зачем вам несколько раз делать один и тот же xpath запрос?

Comment: @aepot еще одно наблюдение: `SelectSingleNode` работает корректно независимо от количества раз запуска метода.

Comment: @aepot в каком смысле несколько раз? А разве можно как-то получить несколько ссылок другим способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден. Что я могу сказать, `HtmlAgilityPack` просто поумнел.

Содержимое тега `<textarea>` он теперь воспринимает не как HTML а как ноду типа `textarea`, что технически вполне логично, поэтому содержимое этой ноды нельзя напрямую получить через xpath. Это просто текст, а не список нод.

Чтобы распарсить это содержимое в список нод, можно пойти таким путем.

```caharp
HD.LoadHtml(responseToString);
HtmlNodeCollection screen = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//textarea[@class='hidearea']");
HD.LoadHtml(screen[0].InnerHtml);
screen = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
```

Код написан грубо, может наградить вас исключениями, поэтому обработка ошибок на вашей совести. Я просто показываю смысл всей этой истории с `<textarea>`